# Selenium and iframe in html

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

Unable to use `send_keys()` on an element inside an iframe. How can I select this iframe, and which element inside should be used for `send_keys()`?

[image: page image]

Here's the html code of the iframe:

```
<iframe class="textarea" src="/framework/html/blank.html" style="width: 99%; border-width: 1px; height: 332px;">
#document
<html webdriver="true">
<head>
</head>
<body> … </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

**How can I send text to the Description area?**

And how can I view the page source of the iframe if it doesn't appear when using "View Page Source" in the browser?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))` assuming that driver is a healthy instance of webdriver. To continue with the default content do `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

**EDIT**: When you have switched to needed frame, locate your webelement as you always do. I guess (but not sure) in your case this will be a html/body, so

`el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('html/body')`

should be fine. And perform

`el.send_keys('keys_to_send')`

**EDIT2**: Before sending keys you may have to focus on the element (click should do the thing, a child element should appear). Or you can just place the needed text via JS.

`driver.execute_script('document.body.innerHTML = "%s"' % text_var)`

Comment: sorry i am a newbie. but driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")) how to use this thing to send key to description windows? like now driver has switched to frame

Comment: @RATHI Edited an answer as you requested

Comment: element <body>got select, the send_keys() is also executing without error but value is not coming on the page.

Comment: Hey there, was using this answer as a reference. You use driver.switch_to_frame, but the documentation on their site uses driver.switch_to.frame. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

The Accepted answer works very well for the given question. However I have two reasons for adding one more answer and hope this answer might help someone landing this question with different ask.

**Reason 1:**

Accepted answer has one way of handling iframes inside a web page. However there are different ways to handle iframes.

- By using index position of the frame
- By using name of the frame
- By using id of the frame

**Reason 2:**

It uses **driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")** statement to find iframe element which may not work or return expected iframe web element when there are multiple iframe elements in the same page.

There are many articles out there to explain handling iframes in detail.

1. http://allselenium.info/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to the [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) using multiple approaches as per the prevailing condition of the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

- If the `<iframe>` is the only *iframe* within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) you can use the following line of code:

  - Using *TAG_NAME*:

    ```
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
    ```
- Locating the `<iframe>` element with a unique [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *css_selector*:

    ```
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.textarea[src='/framework/html/blank.html']"))
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='textarea' and @src='/framework/html/blank.html']"))
    ```

---

Ideally to switch to an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *TAG_NAME* (only iframe present):

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.textarea[src='/framework/html/blank.html']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css_selecor"))).send_keys("character_sequence")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='textarea' and @src='/framework/html/blank.html']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='TlogBtn']/span[@class='mailicn']/img"))).send_keys("character_sequence")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle iframes on a web page you need to switch to the iframes first that are present on the page using this command:
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_id)

This tutorial has a working example of [handling iframe using selenium with python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfdWF4vBZ2o) which will made you able to get through this issue.