# Getting list of items from popup with selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

How to extract the list ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3'] from the following block which is within the popup using Selenium python API.

```
...
<div class="categoryPopup" id="categoryPopup">
<div class="categoriesList"><li id="addCategory_231329891" class="edit_form_add_category">
            <input id="checkCategory_231329891" class="fl" type="checkbox"><label for="checkCategory_231329891"><span class="title fl">Cat1</span></label>
            <div class="cb"></div>
        </li><div class="cb"></div><li id="addCategory_231329901" class="edit_form_add_category">
            <input id="checkCategory_231329901" class="fl" type="checkbox"><label for="checkCategory_231329901"><span class="title fl">Cat2</span></label>
            <div class="cb"></div>
        </li><div class="cb"></div><li id="addCategory_231330011" class="edit_form_add_category">
            <input id="checkCategory_231330011" class="fl" type="checkbox"><label for="checkCategory_231330011"><span class="title fl">Cat3</span></label>
            <div class="cb"></div>
</div>
...
```

Tried to use the following code to no avail:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://targeURL")
# series of successful browser.get_element_by...
browser.get_element_by_class_name("categoriesList") # fails with NoSuchElementException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using cssSelector as follows. I am assuming you want to select all the checkboxes. The following code will return the list of inputs. You also should be using `_elements_` to find the collection of elements. See the [api](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) doc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://targeURL")
# series of successful browser.get_element_by...
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#categoryPopup input")
```

Comment: Thank you, though still getting NoSuchElementException

Comment: @user1264304 is there any `iframe` involved?

Comment: Yes, it does. If the elements inside the `iframe` you need to switch to inside the frame first then look for the element. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924146/selenium-and-iframe-in-html)

Comment: Thank you, i tried `browser.switch_to.active_element` (active element is u" iframe") and then the lines you suggested. Still getting the same error. Tried getting the xpath and css from Firebug. Finding by them results still in `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @user1264304 Nope. You need to use `switch_to_frame("name of frame")` See [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=frame#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame). `switch_to.active_element()` and `switch_to_frame("name of frame")` are not same

Comment: Thank you. I haven't used `switch_to_frame("name of frame")` because the frame doesn't have a name attribute - `<iframe src="src_url" iframe-event-listener="messageHandler(event)" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" class="ng-isolate-scope"></iframe>`

Comment: You can use `xpath` or `cssSelctor` or any element locating strategies to locate the `iframe`.  Eg: `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[iframe-event-listener='messageHandler(event)']"))` see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534622/selecting-an-iframe-using-python-selenium)