# selenium does not retrieve html

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to retrieve all fields from this web page:

https://www.jobsbank.gov.sg/ICMSPortal/portlets/JobBankHandler/SearchDetail.do?id=JOB-2016-0008786

However, when I run my code, it does not even seem to retrieve the HTML. I'm wondering what is it about the page that makes it unable to retrieve the HTML (I use PhantomJS.exe headless browser but that shouldn't make a difference), does this have anything to do with iframe? If so, how do I use selenium to deal with this?

I've used selenium with phantomJS to scrape from http://www.indeed.com/resumes/-/in-Singapore successfully, but the same method doesn't seem to work for the website mentioned above. Please refer to my code below

```
import re
import math
import time
import requests
from lxml import html
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

def getPageEnd(url):
    payload = {
        "{actionForm.checkValidRequest}": "YES",
        "{actionForm.recordsPerPage}": "20",
        "{actionForm.sortBy}": "1",
        "{actionForm.searchType}": "Quick Search",
        "{actionForm.currentPageNumber}": "1"
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    tree = html.fromstring(r.text)

    page_list = tree.xpath('//div[@class="searchetails"]/p/'
                           'span[@style="color: #b41b84;"]/text()')
    page_list = re.findall('\d+', page_list[0])
    page_end = page_list[-1]
    page_end = int(page_end)/100.0
    page_end = math.ceil(page_end) #rounding up
    return int(page_end)


def jobScrape(url, pagenum):
    job_link_url_prepend = "__https://www.jobsbank.gov.sg"

    payload = {
        "{actionForm.checkValidRequest}": "YES",
        "{actionForm.recordsPerPage}": "20",
        "{actionForm.sortBy}": "1",
        "{actionForm.searchType}": "Quick Search",
        "{actionForm.currentPageNumber}": "%s" % pagenum,
    }
    while True:
        try:
            r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            print("Exception ConnectionError was caught, retrying requests...")
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            break

    tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
    cur_page_job_links = [job_link_url_prepend + i for i in 
                          tree.xpath('//td[@class="jobDesActive"]/a/@href')] 

    print("Done scraping page %s" % pagenum)

    return cur_page_job_links


def main():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'E:\desktop\phantomjs.exe')
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
    url = "https://www.jobsbank.gov.sg/ICMSPortal/portlets/JobBankHandler/SearchResult3.do"
    page_start = 1
    page_end = getPageEnd(url)

    for pagenum in range(page_start, 2):
        cur_page_job_links = jobScrape(url, str(pagenum))

        with open("link.txt", 'a') as f:
            for link in cur_page_job_links:
                f.write("%s \n" % link)
    for link in cur_page_job_links:
        url = "__https://" + link
        driver.get(url)
        htmltext = driver.page_source
        print htmltext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think it might have something to do with wanting to retrieve JobDescription frame, how do I use a command like window.document.getElementById("frameJobDescription")  to get what I want?

Comment: Which element are you unable to fetch? Please post a [Minimal and Complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hi @JasonEstibeiro, I am unable to fetch the Job Description frame for example

Comment: Because it is in an Iframe.

Comment: @Vaulstein, how do I use selenium retrieve an Iframe? What about other fields like "Posting date", and "Salary" that are not Iframes? I actually want to retrieve every piece of data on that web page

Comment: You can find a way to retrieve the content of an Iframe [here- get Iframe content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924146/selenium-and-iframe-in-html)

Comment: I would suggest you should use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) to get the content you want from the pages

Comment: @Vaulstein Thank you referring me to that link! Can I just ask briefly, how is scrapy useful for this sort of thing? Do you mean scrapy to replace selenium?

Comment: @stochastiq: Yes, you can do that or use both together. Xpaths can be used in scrapy to retrieve elements.