# "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element" while clicking a 'Next' button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I’m trying to click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button using Selenium, I've tried with the code below, but it ends in error.

The element

```html
<input type="submit" name="submitNext" value="Next">
```

My code

```python
driver.find_element_by_name("submitNext").click()
```

But then it outputs these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thomas/PycharmProjects/test/mainapp/main.py", line 194, in
<module>
    visa()
  File "C:/Users/thomas/PycharmProjects/test/mainapp/main.py", line 174, in visa
driver.find_element_by_name("submitNext").click()
  File "C:\Users\thomas\PycharmProjects\BudgetMain\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 487, in find_element_by_name
return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\thomas\PycharmProjects\BudgetMain\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\thomas\PycharmProjects\BudgetMain\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\thomas\PycharmProjects\BudgetMain\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"submitNext"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.170)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

How can I click that button without errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"submitNext"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.170)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to locate the desired element.

### Locating the desired element

As per the HTML you have shared to click on the element you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='submitNext'][value='Next']").click()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='submitNext' and @value='Next']").click()
  ```

However your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.36*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following:

> Supports **Chrome v63-65**

- You are using *chrome=66.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following:

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* **v2.36** and the *Chrome Browser* **v66.0**

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: For future readers who found they were using an outdated version of _Chromedriver_, the following url `chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` will always return the version number of the latest release, which can the be used within `http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/version_number/chromedriver_linux64.zip` to _always_ download the latest version of _Chromedriver_.