# Selenium in Python: "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, frame, webdriverwait

I tried typing 'abc' in the first block of id and 'cdef' in the second block of password.

However, the error code at the bottom comes up.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver.get('http://sugang.korea.ac.kr')
```

I added an implicit wait to prevent the code from executing before the page fully loads.

`driver.implicitly_wait(30)`

Code for adding username and password is as below:

`driver.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys('abc')`
`driver.find_element_by_name('pw').send_keys('cdef')`

But I am getting the below error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *username* and *password* fields are within an `frame`, so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://sugang.korea.ac.kr")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"firstF")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input_login[name='id']"))).send_keys('abc')
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.input_login[name='pw']").send_keys("cdef")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: sugang_korea_ac_kr]

Answer (score 10):

The 'No Such Element' exception usually comes when web driver can't see the element you are trying to perform an action on.

Reasons can be:

1. your ID or Name or XPath or CssSelector can be wrong.
2. Your element might be inside an an iframe so that web driver can't see or detect it. *[Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python)*
3. Your element is taking time to appear on the UI, so you can use an explicit wait to solve this. See [5. Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add explicitly wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

userNameElement= WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "id"))
userNameElement.send_keys('abc')

pwdElement= WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "pwd"))
pwdElement.send_keys('cdef')
```

Here, I am expecting that your locators are correct.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-7-29d0ea4b437a>", line 14
    pwdElement.send_keys('cdef')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax pwdElement.send is a invaild syntex...

Comment: Does it passed the first block i.e. adding username?

Comment: @youngyoung Might be there was issue while copy pasting the code for qoute. Try adding quote manually.

Answer (score 1):

It is in a frame which you need to switch to first. Also, use ids where possible as they are faster.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url ="http://sugang.korea.ac.kr"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[name=firstF]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=firstF]'))
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'id'))).send_keys('abc')
driver.find_element_by_id('pw').send_keys('def')
driver.find_element_by_id('loginButton').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The site you are trying to access does not have an element with a tag name id. Examine the site carefully.

```html
<input name="id">
```

If the input has an id value, try this;

```python
driver.find_element_by_id("id")
```

Example Use:

HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password">
</div>
<button id="btn-login"  type="submit">Enter</button>
```

Python:

```python
username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys("your_username")
password.send_keys("your_password")

driver.find_element_by_id("btn-login").click()
```