# How to web scrape a cartography/map - selenium not working

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, dictionary, screen-scraping

I am trying to get the adresses for all postal access points in Belgium from this site: https://www.ibpt.be/en/consumers/post/cartography

I am using Selenium with python 3, and I can't seem to get it to work, even though it normally works on other sites. I figure it might be because the map is special in some way? (But I thought this is when Selenium is actually necessary).

Below is the very simple code I am trying to get to work (eventually I need to also paste a zip code and save the results, but first off, I can't even get it to click the search button).

Anyone who can help? (btw, if there is an easier and faster way to do this (without Selenium), please do share).

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"XXX\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.ibpt.be/en/consumers/post/cartography")

time.sleep(3)

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body > app-root > div > app-filter > div > div.content > div > form > div.max-height-search-button > div > input')))
time.sleep(3)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > app-root > div > app-filter > div > div.content > div > form > div.max-height-search-button > div > input')).perform()
time.sleep(3)
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > app-root > div > app-filter > div > div.content > div > form > div.max-height-search-button > div > input')
search.click()
```

Comment: page sends POST request to url https://www.postalpoint.be/geoserver/post_uat_wfs/wfs to get some data - you can see more details in `DevTool` in Firefox/Chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium and iframe in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924146/selenium-and-iframe-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.ibpt.be/en/consumers/post/cartography')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='postalpoint']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.search-location-button>input.bt-search[value='Search']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.ibpt.be/en/consumers/post/cartography')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src, 'postalpoint')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='search-location-button']/input[@class='bt-search' and @value='Search']"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Belgian_Institute_for_Postal_services]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)