# How to close iframe selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, popup

1 click button in website it shown iframe like popup and I can edit it but I cant close iframe I try to use X button but when mouse focus in button it change the class name and shown text on mouse , it don't have id.

this is source of button

```
<a class="jbox-close" title="Close" onmouseover="$(this).addClass('jbox-close-hover');" onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('jbox-close-hover');" style="position:absolute; display:block; cursor:pointer; top:11px; right:11px; width:15px; height:15px;"></a>

this is code focus mouse
<a class="jbox-close jbox-close-hover" title="Close" onmouseover="$(this).addClass('jbox-close-hover');" onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('jbox-close-hover');" style="position:absolute; display:block; cursor:pointer; top:11px; right:11px; width:15px; height:15px;"></a>
```

this is my code

```
        for link in tittle:
            a = link.get_attribute('title')
            if (a == "Packaging Details"):
                link.click()
                time.sleep(2)
                print(driver.current_url)
                iframe=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
                driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
                time.sleep(2)
                print(driver.find_element_by_id("width").get_attribute('value'))
                print(type(driver.find_element_by_id("width").get_attribute('value')))
                print(widthctn)
                driver.find_element_by_id("width").send_keys("",widthctn)
                time.sleep(1)
                driver.find_element_by_name("btnSave").click()
                time.sleep(1)
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
``
and this error
```

raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dtung/PycharmProjects/BS4/multiple tab.py", line 79, in 
    link.click()
  File "C:\Users\dtung\miniconda3\envs\BS4\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\dtung\miniconda3\envs\BS4\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\dtung\miniconda3\envs\BS4\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\dtung\miniconda3\envs\BS4\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (257, 505). Other element would receive the click: 
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.113)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about iframes, you can find your answer here [Selenium and iframe in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924146/selenium-and-iframe-in-html),

But your error looks like some element/alert is hiding your actual element where you want to click. You can achieve click using js executor if element is not visible or hidden by some other element.
eg: assuming click is failed,

```
btnSave = driver.find_element_by_name("btnSave")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', btnSave)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it opens 2 frames,Your answers help me solve the problem but I want to learn more about how to close it to be able to optimize.
NOTE: hiding element is link.click() it open iframe

Comment: your code looks like you are referring to windows, in that case you can close it using  driver.close()
and if you want to switch out of iframe, use this driver.switch_to.default_content()

Comment: driver.close() it close page. driver.switch_to.default_content() it still can't close iframe just switch out iframe and Many iframes overlap.

Comment: It would be good if you can provide page source or url, how you are trying to close iframe. In general there is no way we can close iframe. But we can remove it from page using js.

Comment: sorry but I can't. Where can I find out about it, js. i just beginner and hope learning more.
P/S:when I code driver.find_element_by_id("width").get_attribute('value') if attribute doesn't exist Is my code faulty?.Thanks U again

Answer (score 0):

You can't close iframe instead of that once you finished processsing elements on a iframe you can switch control back to your parent window using `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

[find more on how to handle iframes](https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-iframes-selenium-python/)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need to close current frame to open another frame to edit.

Comment: In that case you can dirrectly use driver.switch_to.default_content() to switch back to parent window and then use driver.switch_to.frame(element) to handle your next iframe

Comment: I just updated my code above and the error may be not clickable.

Comment: provide your url

Comment: Sorry but i can't provide url but maybe this URL work the same
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://ncov.moh.gov.vn/

Comment: i try to use time.sleep(10) and during time sleep I close iframe manual handling. and no error