# Selenium cannot locate element in popup window

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to automate some online activity, but I am stuck at this popup.
[image: the the facebook cookie acceptance pop up window].

After waiting I am using the XPath: `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_8_gw"]').click()`

But that gives me this exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="u_0_8_gw"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
```

I have also tried using the full path and the id and CSS selector, but none worked. Any suggestions?

Update: HTML code (cannot add as text)

[image: HTML code]

Also, my button is inside this div.
[image: div]

Comment: Is the popup in an iframe? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924146/selenium-and-iframe-in-html

Comment: Checked based on [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-a-webpage-is-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-into-the-browser-window-using-javascript/), and it is not in an iframe.

Comment: @SzèlesÀron There can be multiple reasons of not working because you have not provided the DOM? please share the html. It can be an alert, it can be inside shadow root, might be the locator is not correct etc. So please share the DOM or share the URL.

Comment: @QualityMatters added HTML

Comment: Your locator does not look correct. Can you check with this in your dom? Is it highlighting your element?  //button[@data-testid='cookie-policy-dialog-accept-button']

Comment: @QualityMatters no it does not highlight it.

Comment: @SzèlesÀron Can you share the url, how you are reaching there?

Comment: @QualityMatters I am being directed to the shown popup after clicking on "login with Facebook", so you would not be able to access the link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to direct the webdriver to the pop-up window. If you can provide the pop window HTML code. I can show you how to direct the webdriver to the particular window. Also, Once you finish interesting the pop-up you need to direct the webdriver to the main window.

The pop-up window looks like an iFrame. If it's an iframe you need to direct webdriver as follow:
If the iframe has an ID execute bellow command

```
    driver.switchTo().frame("<iframeId>"); 
    //afterwards execute your click event
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_8_gw"]').click()
```

Comment: It is not in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If NoSuchElementException accrued and xpath is right then the scroll to target button :

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH OF Target button))
```

Comment: Still returns the same exception

Answer (score 0):

You must use xpath selection, which does not change in every request that is made. You are trying to capture it according to the id of the element, but the id changes, so it cannot be found.

In your case

`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-cookiebanner="accept_button"]').click()`